# what is the regular expression for the automaton?

Tags: finite-automata

In this automaton how to find regular expression

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a straightforward application of computer science and unrelated to programming.

Answer (score 0):

There are three methods basically. Two are given in the book by Hopcroft and Ullman.

1) Calucalte R_ij recursively for all states i,j going through only k intermediate states.

2) Calculate regular expression by eliminating states between start state and a single final state. This is simpler than the first method.

3) Analyse and try to understand the DFA itself.

If we eliminate the middle state we have following

a_02 = (aa+ba)*(ab+bb) : Regular expression from state 0 to 2 without using arrow from state 2 to 0.
a_00 = (aa+ba)* : Regular expression from state 0 to 0 without using arrow from state 2 to 0.

We can now use the expression given in the textbook but at this stage we can also analyse the automata and come up with a solution. So finally R_02 becomes

((aa+ba)*(ab+bb)(a+b))*(aa+ba)*(ab+bb)